# Equal sized table cells to fill the entire width of the containing table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there a way using HTML/CSS (with relative sizing) to make a row of cells stretch the entire width of the table within which it is contained?

The cells should be equal widths and the outer table size is also dynamic with `<table width="100%">`.

Currently if I don't specify a fixed size; the cells just autosize to fit their contents.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You don't even have to set a specific width for the cells, `table-layout: fixed` suffices to spread the cells evenly.

```css
ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    vertical-align: middle;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo<br>foo</li>
  <li>barbarbarbarbar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

> Note that for `table-layout` to work the table styled element must have a width set (100% in my example).

Comment: this solution is better, and should work even with dynamically generated columns

Comment: If a string exceeds the td max width, you're in trouble

Comment: Adding `word-wrap:break-word` will fix this issue, as I just discovered

Answer (score 126):

Just use percentage widths and [fixed table layout](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html#tablelayout):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

with

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
td { width: 33%; }
```

Fixed table layout is important as otherwise the browser will adjust the widths as it sees fit if the contents don't fit ie the widths are otherwise a suggestion not a rule without fixed table layout.

Obviously, adjust the CSS to fit your circumstances, which usually means applying the styling only to a tables with a given class or possibly with a given ID.

Comment: and make sure you're td selector doesn't select other td's involved :D

Comment: you don't need to set width of `td` because you may have dynamic number of columns… and it works without it through.

Answer (score 6):

Using `table-layout: fixed` as a property for `table` and `width: calc(100%/3);` for `td` (*assuming there are 3 `td`'s*). With these two properties set, the *table cells* will be *equal* in size.

Refer to the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/4L4yjL9h/).

Comment: You don't need them both, either solution alone would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this lines to your table style:

```
#table_name{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You have a good example on this [codepan](https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/jALALm).

This is late answer, but it will help for future searches.