# tr tbody scroll with 100% width

Tags: html, css

I looked for another question but couldn't find it

https://jsfiddle.net/0u15em89/

```css
table>tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

add scroll to tbody,

I want to make the width 100% by removing the space between td and scroll.

Is it possible to do without fixing the width of td?

Comment: Please check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457563/equal-sized-table-cells-to-fill-the-entire-width-of-the-containing-table . you can use table-layout: fixed; and equal width to cells.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't fix the width of th or tr.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly , you may be able to get a full width by the style below :

```
table { 
width: 100%; 
border-spacing: 0; 
}

table tbody, table thead { 
 display: block; 
}  

thead tr th { 
height: 40px;  
line-height: 40px; 
} 

table tbody { 
height: 50px;  
overflow-y: auto; 
overflow-x: hidden;  
} 

tbody td, thead th { 
width : 200px; 
} 
td { 
text-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: I can't fixed the width  Because the width changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, First, Remove this whole part

```
 table>tbody {
      display: block;
      max-height: 50px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

second, surround a table tag with a `div` tag 
**Ex :** `<div><table>......</table></div>`.
 make that `div` tag scroll like this,

```
div {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just want to use tbody, not div.

Answer (score 0):

Apply below `css` to tr will help you to fix the `width` issue without providing specific width to `td`.

```css
table>tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: auto;
  display: inherit;
}

tr {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>content1</td>
      <td>content2</td>
      <td>content3</td>
      <td>content4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it now

Comment: jsfiddle ran, but on my web it was pushed to the right.